# append() to stuct that only has one slice field in golang

Tags: go

I want to append an element to a struct that only consists of a single annonymous slice:

```
package main

type List []Element

type Element struct {
    Id string
}

func (l *List) addElement(id string) {
    e := &Element{
        Id: id,
    }
    l = append(l, e)
}

func main() {
    list := List{}
    list.addElement("test")
}
```

That does not work, since addElement does not know l as slice but as *List:

```
go run plugin.go
# command-line-arguments
./plugin.go:13: first argument to append must be slice; have *List
```

What most likely would work is to go like this:

```
type List struct {
    elements []Element
}
```

and fix the addElement func accordingly. I there a nicer way than that, eg. one that let me keep the first definition of type List?

Many thanks, sontags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems,

1. You're appending `*Element` to `[]Element`, either use `Element{}` or change the list to `[]*Element`.
2. You need to dereference the slice in `addElement`.

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/bb_Zn8vMe6):

```
func (l *List) addElement(id string) {
    e := Element{
        Id: id,
    }
    *l = append(*l, e)
}
```

Comment: go run plugin.go
    # command-line-arguments
    ./plugin.go:15: cannot use append(*l, e) (type []Element) as type     List in assignment